# OpenGL Fog Coordinate Extension in Windows

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to use fog coordinate extension with OpenGL under Windows. Below are the first few lines of my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>
#include "GLEXT.h"

#define GL_FOG_COORDINATE_SOURCE_EXT    0x8450      
#define GL_FOG_COORDINATE_EXT       0x8451                  

PFNGLFOGCOORDFEXTPROC glFogCoordfEXT = NULL;

glFogCoordfEXT = (PFNGLFOGCOORDFEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glFogCoordfEXT");
```

If that, the compiler hints that glFogCoordfEXT cannot be found. But once I put

```
glFogCoordfEXT = (PFNGLFOGCOORDFEXTPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glFogCoordfEXT");
```

before the fog parameter settings, the compiling passed and the the program runs well.

I'm not familiar with the Windows specific function calls though I'm using Windows a lot. Could anyone tell me how this works?

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft Windows you compile with one library (the `.lib` one), and run with a different library (your `.dll` ones).  Microsoft controls the contents of the compilation library, but vendors are able to replace the runtime one.  In OpenGL's case, the compilation library is quite old (only supports OpenGL 1.1 functions and a few extensions), and since that library provides the exported functions the compiler needs for linking, new OpenGL functions aren't included there.  As such, the use of *function pointers* was required, as they can be retrieved at runtime from a .dll.  The function `wglGetProcAddress()` does that function retrieval, and all of those types you see in capital letters (e.g., `PFNGLFOGCOORDFEXTPROC`) are typedefs for the function that you can get with `wglGetProcAddress()`.  So, in order to use your `glFogCoordfEXT()` function, you needed to retrieve it from the .dll before you called it.  Generally, you should collect all the functions that you need to use `wglGetProcAddress()` to get in your initialization code at the start of your program (but after you've created your OpenGL context).

Another point: you should verify that the appropriate version of OpenGL is available (by calling `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, and that any extensions you might need are supported (by calling either `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` and parsing the string, or if you're using a more recent OpenGL, call `glGetStringi()` to get individual extension strings).  `wglGetProcAddress()` will return `NULL` if the function isn't available in your OpenGL implementation.  It will return a valid function pointer is available, but that doesn't necessarily mean the functionality you require is present (which is why you should check the extension string).  That situation is rare, but can occur due to extension interactions.

Comment: Or you could just use a [proper OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) and not have to care.

Comment: Which is truly the simplest answer.